# I can't load data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I can connect to Elasticsearch but I can't load data in, when I checked the status using this command line :

```sh
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_status'
```

I get this message error:

```js
{
  "error":{
    "root_cause":[
      {
        "type":"invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason":"Invalid index name [_status], must not start with '_'.",
        "index_uuid":"_na_",
        "index":"_status"
      }
    ],
    "type":"invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason":"Invalid index name [_status], must not start with '_'.",
    "index_uuid":"_na_",
    "index":"_status"
  },
  "status":400
}
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: looks like your index name is starting with `.` , can you please share your api using which you are creating index and inserting a document

Comment: Can you please help how can I get those information? I tried this command line _cat API doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell me how you created your index?

Comment: Dict = {"times" : date, "Key1": Key1_dict, "Key2" : Key2_dict, "Key3" :  Key3_dict, "Key4" : Key4_dict}
logFile.write("preprocessing executed succesfully")
try:
  es.index(index="my_prog-{}.{}.{}".format(year,month,day), doc_type='timeWindow', body=Dict)
  es.indices.refresh(index="my_prog-{}.{}.{}".format(year,month,day))
except Exception as e:
  logFile.write("Can't load data into ElasticSearch: {}\n".format(str(e)))

Comment: the result of running the code : 
preprocessing executed succesfully
Can't load data into ElasticSearch

Comment: `_status` endpoint has been [deprecated since 1.2 and removed since 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-status.html). To check which indexes are present you can run `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`. Also plain `curl http://localhost:9200/_search` will return all documents in your cluster. May you please elaborate your question with output of these two queries, and also specify which versions of Elasticsearch and python library do you use?

Comment: yes It returns some old documents not those that I m loading actually, for the ES version I m using 6.2.4 python2.7

Comment: This is the error message 
TypeError("Unable to serialize time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=2, tm_min=40, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=253, tm_isdst=-1) (type: <type 'time.struct_time'>)",))